Error in filament 3, when using multiple files with FileUpload
I have the following migration file:
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('slug')->unique();
$table->string('image')->nullable();
$table->longText('description')->nullable();
$table->decimal('price', 10,2);

This is my model:
protected $fillable = [
 'category_id',
 'brand_id',
 'name',
 'slug',
 'image',
 'description',
 'price',
 'is_active',
 'is_featured',
 'in_stock',
 'on_sale'
];

protected $casts = [
  'images' => 'array'
];

and this is my resource
FileUpload::make('images')
  ->multiple()
  ->reorderable()
  ->maxFiles(5)
  ->required()
  ->directory('products')

When reloading, the images are not deleted, they are stored in the specified folder, but when refreshing the page, they disappear. It is only when reloading the page the images disappear.

This line $table->string('image')->nullable() is not magically becoming protected $casts = ['images' => 'array'] ..
